# can oracle hints be used to defer a (pl/sql) condition till last?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to optimise a select (cursor in pl/sql code actually) that includes a pl/sql function e.g.

```
    select * from mytable t,mytable2 t2...
where t.thing = 'XXX'
... lots more joins and sql predicate on various columns
and myplsqlfunction(t.val) = 'X'
```

The myplsqlfunction() is very expensive, but is only applicable to a manageably small subset of the other conditions.
The problem is that Oracle appears to evaluating myplsqlfunction() on more data than is ideal. 
My evidence for this is if I recast the above as either

```
select * from (
        select * from mytable t,mytable2 t2...
    where t.thing = 'XXX'
    ... lots more joins and sql predicate on various columns
) where myplsqlfunction(t.val) = 'X'
```

or pl/sql as:

```
begin
for t in ( select * from mytable t,mytable2 t2...
        where t.thing = 'XXX'
        ... lots more joins and sql predicate on various columns ) loop
   if myplsqlfunction(t.val) = 'X' then
       -- process the desired subset
   end if;
end loop;
end;
```

performance is an order of magnitude better.

I am resigned to restructuring the offending code to use either of the 2 above idioms, but it would be delighted if there was any simpler way to get the Oracle optimizer to do this for me.

Comment: When you restructure the code, you should also start using explicit `JOIN` syntax rather than implicit joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify a bunch of hints to force a particular plan.  But that would almost assuredly be more of a pain than restructuring the code.

I would expect that what you really want to do is to [associate non-default statistics with the function](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=426).  If you tell Oracle that the function is less selective than the optimizer is guessing or (more likely) if you provide high values for the CPU or I/O cost of the function, you'll cause the optimizer to try to call the function as few times as possible.  The oracle-developer.net article walks through how to pick reasonably correct values for the cost (or going a step beyond that how to make those statistics change over time as the cost of the function call changes).  You can probably fix your immediate problem by setting crazy-high costs but you probably want to go to the effort of setting accurate values so that you're giving the optimizer the most accurate information possible.  Setting costs way too high or way too low tends to cause some set of queries to do something stupid.

Comment: Thanks Justin. Indeed, restructuring isn't so difficult, and at least makes the decision explicit and permanent.  While defining non-default stats is interesting, I would worry about their lack of visibility to other developers. So I will go with the restructuring

Answer (score 0):

You can use WITH clause to first evaluate all your join conditions and get a manageable subset of data. Then you can go for the pl/sql Function on the subset of data. But it all depends on the volume still you can try this. Let me know for any issues.

Comment: The optimizer is under no more obligation to evaluate a CTE before applying other predicates than it is to evaluate an inline view rather than pushing predicates into the inline view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE like:

```
WITH X as
( select /*+ MATERIALIZE */ * from mytable t,mytable2 t2...
    where t.thing = 'XXX'
    ... lots more joins and sql predicate on various columns
) 
SELECT * FROM X
where myplsqlfunction(t.val) = 'X';
```

Note the Materiliaze hint. CTEs can be either inlined or materialized(into TEMP tablespace).

Another option would be to use `NO_PUSH_PRED` hint. This is generally better solution (avoids materializing of the subquery), but it requires some tweaking.

PS: you should **not** call another SQL from myplsqlfunction. This SQL might see data added after your query started and you might get surprising results.

You can also declare your function as RESULT_CACHE, to force the Oracle to remember return values from the function - if applicable i.e. the amount of possible function's parameter values is reasonably small.

Probably the best solution is to associate the stats, as Justin describes.